How to remove/replace the last line of a nifi flow file content
Hi I have my flow file as like below, while doing sql query i got the data but i got one extra last line, so i want to remove it using nifi replace text processor, any help is appreciated.
111 AAA
222 BBB
333 CCC
444 DDD
<THIS IS THE EXTRA ROW I HAVE>

output should be like below
111 AAA
222 BBB
333 CCC
444 DDD


use ReplaceText processor with parameters:
Search Value:      (?s)(\A.*?)[^\r\n]*[\r\n]*\Z
Replacement Value: $1

this should remove the last line from your text
https://regex101.com/r/tzMzWW/1
